# Can any one tell me whats wrong here in the code

Tags: php, mysqli

Please let me know whats wrong here.

Getting this error:

> Please Check Your Query when submitting

```
        <?php

        if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
            if ( empty( $_POST[ 'subcat' ] ) ) {
                echo '<span style="color: red;"> Please Fill in the Category Name</span> ';
            } else {


                $subcat = $_POST[ 'subcat' ];


                $query = " insert into subcategory (scatname) values('$subcat')";
                $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );

                if ( $result ) {
                    echo '<span style="color: green;">Category Added Successfully</span>';
                } else {
                    echo '  Please Check Your Query ';
                }
            }
        }

        ?>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <lable>Sub Category Name</lable>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subcat"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <lable>Select Category</lable>
                <select class="form_control" name="cat">
                    <?php 

    $query="select * from category";
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){



    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['catname']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php 
            }   
    }       
        ?>
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code as `code`,

Comment: ??? explain please

Comment: What are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: need to to know whats wrong in the code as i am not able to add subcategories by selecting categories  getting error - please check query not able to get whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

The query fails because you didn't escape the string `$subcat`.

```
$subcat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[ 'subcat' ]);

$query = "INSERT into subcategory (scatname) VALUES ('$subcat')";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );
```

You can read more about it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php